# .NET MAUI: how to control IsVisible property according an object in the model

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a model that has an observable property called `visitor` (which is an object having a bool property called `valid`).

That `visitor` property will be `null` at the beginning of execution, but according to some condition, that `visitor` is instantiated and the `valid` property is assigned `true` or `false`.

In the corresponding XAML file, I have these 2 layouts:

```
<StackLayout 
    x:Name="AllowedMessage"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    IsVisible="{Binding Visitor.valid}">
    ....
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout 
    x:Name="DeniedMessage"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    IsVisible="{Binding Visitor.valid, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}">
    ...
</StackLayout>
```

Please see `IsVisible` property of both layouts.

The first one has `IsVisible="{Binding Visitor.valid}"` and the second one `IsVisible="{Binding Visitor.valid, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}"`

The behaviour should be this according to `visitor` property:

- At app startup, both layouts should be hidden (`visitor` property is `null`)
- When at some point `visitor` is instantiated and `valid` property is `true`. In this case, first layout should be shown.
- Finally, when `visitor` is instantiated and `valid` property is `false`, second layout should be shown.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In the InvertedBoolConverter do you handle null values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the default value of bool type is `false`, so initially, the second layout is displayed and the first layout is hidden.

And after testing on my side, if the `visitor` property is `null`, both the first and the second layout will visible at first.

To achieve your needs, you can try to define two different variables for the two layouts.

You can follow the following steps:

1.add two variables `Valid` and `Valid2`,and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for this model `Visitor`.

```
public class Visitor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _valid=false;
    public bool Valid
    {
        get { return _valid; }
        set {
            SetProperty(ref _valid, value);

            updateValue(_valid);
        }
    }

    private bool _valid2 = false;
    public bool Valid2
    {
        get { return _valid2; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _valid2, value); }
    }


    void updateValue(bool value) {
        Valid2 =!value;
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                    return false;
                storage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
                return true;
            }
            protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

2.create a viewmodel `MyViewModel.cs`

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Visitor _visitor;
    public Visitor Visitor
    {
        get { return _visitor; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _visitor, value);
        }
    }
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel() {
        TestCommand = new Command(TestMethod);

        // initialize Visitor and the inner properties `Valid` and `Valid2`
        Visitor = new Visitor();
        Visitor.Valid = false;
        Visitor.Valid2 = false;
    }

    private void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        // change the value of Valid and Valid2
        Visitor.Valid = !Visitor.Valid;
        Visitor.Valid2 = !Visitor.Valid;
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

3.Usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    <!--<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>-->

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MyViewModel></local:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">

            <StackLayout  
                HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                x:Name="AllowedMessage"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="End"
               IsVisible="{Binding Visitor.Valid}">
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout
                HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Green"
                x:Name="DeniedMessage"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                IsVisible="{Binding Visitor.Valid2}">
            </StackLayout>
            <Button  Text="test" Command="{ Binding TestCommand}" Margin="10"/>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```